# notify driver that eos has been reached

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-mediaplayer

why this error occurs?

I am playin video from url.1 minustes later says: video cant played.
And this error occurs.

```
 String urll=path;


vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    vd.setVideoPath(urll);
```

[image]

```
    vd.requestFocus();
    vd.start();
```

Comment: output eos has been reached what is this?

Comment: and what is allocate done for all ip buffers it says that